# $routeProvider not loading template

Tags: angularjs

update: Problem turns out to be accidental clear of all modules in the service.

This is the commit that works, [repo](https://github.com/lianliu/SF-Muni/tree/474eb3614d478ebfb70c0dc2be3e9ef064dfbe9c). And this is the code that causes the problem, [link](https://github.com/lianliu/SF-Muni/blob/master/app/scripts/services/muniService.js). I still have no idea what's going wrong here.

After some trials, I think that it is because I use promise to fetch data. I also use d3Promise in the app, and get the same bug, the directive not loaded again (and this time, menu directive also fails).

A strange bug.

After I added menu directive, the map directive is not loaded into to the page. It was in the page before that.

no error, both in chrome console and grunt server.

I spent some time debugging. I found that the $routeProvider is not working. It only changes the url, but not loads the partials and binds controllers of partials.

Below is the code:

in index.html:

```
<body ng-app="SFM">
<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h3 class="text-muted">SF-Muni</h3>
    <a ng-href="#/about" class="btn">about</a>
  </div>

  <div menu></div>

  <div ng-view></div>
 </div>
 <!-- other vender files -->
 <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

 <!-- utilities -->

 <!-- services -->
 <script src="scripts/services/d3service.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/services/muniService.js"></script>

 <!-- controllers -->
 <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>

 <!-- directives -->
 <script src="scripts/directives/menu.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/directives/map.js"></script>
</body>
```

app.js:

```
'use strict';
angular
    .module('SFM', [
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'd3'
    ])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
           .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
                controller: 'AboutCtrl'
           })
          .otherwise({
               redirectTo: '/'
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you forgot to request the $routeProvider to be injected into the config function.

Try this:

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
       .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutCtrl'
       })
      .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: I'll try, but I clone the angular seed from github. And it worked fine until I include another directive into the app. I mean, $routeProvider worked as expected, and I could go to where I want.